# Create AppleScript as Application Bundle and Set Its Icon

Tags: firefox-addon

Programmatically I'm trying to create an applescript file and set its icon. I make the content easy with OS.File.

I'm trying follow this tutorial here on how to make profile shortcuts on macs:
http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/asa/archives/2008/08/shortcut_to_lau.html

The problem I'm having is I can't set it to be "Application Bundle" and I can't figure out how to set icon.

Comment: I looked at your link. When i opened the script editor and clicked save there was an application option. That is probably what you want.

Comment: I updated my question, I'm trying to do this programatically from XPCOM/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

ok so now we are cooking.

I looked through your link and this is what I found.

I opened the script editor and put this in as my script

```
do shell script "/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator"
```

So this should just open the Calculator, and it does!

After you have this goto File>Save and put the name you want to give it and there should be a field called File Format. Select Application and save it where you want to save it. I put it on my Desktop.

So know you should have a file that when double clicked on it will open the Calculator. If you want to change the icon for this file right click and select "Get Info". Then just drag the image you want the icon to be to the top left image in the Get Info window.

That should do it.

Comment: Yes exctly that. Thanks for this. I plus1 you for making effort on getting through to me even though you couldn't comment.

Comment: Thanks man for trying this is good stuff still but i need to do it programatically. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm making progress on this, however on click of the script.app file its throwing "unidentified author" error and Im trying to figure that out.

I made it applicaiton bundle by simply setting file of compiled script to `.app` instead of `.scpt`.

Anyways this is the work so far:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var path_compile = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'script.app');
var XREExeF = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []).path;

var osacompile = Cc['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
osacompile.initWithPath('/usr/bin/osacompile');

console.log('Script will be compiled at path:', path_compile);

var proc = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
proc.init(osacompile);

var procFinOSA = {
  observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    console.log('incoming procFinOSA', 'aSubject:', aSubject, 'aTopic:', aTopic, 'aData', aData);
    console.log('incoming procFinOSA unevaled', 'aSubject:', uneval(aSubject), 'aTopic:', uneval(aTopic), 'aData', uneval(aData));
  }
};

var userAgent = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http'].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler).userAgent;

if (/Mac OS X 10\.(?:4|5|6)(?!\d)/.test(userAgent)) {
  //Before lion, well just for 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, this is just what Zotero had
  console.log('Compiling for pre-Lion Mac OS X', 'userAgent:', userAgent);
  var args = ['-t', 'osas', '-c', 'ToyS', '-x', '-o', path_compile, '-e', 'do shell script "' + XREExeF + ' -P -no-remote &> /dev/null &"'];
  proc.runAsync(args, args.length, procFinOSA);
} else {
  //Lion and after (so >= 10.7)
  console.log('Compiling for Lion or later Mac OS X', 'userAgent:', userAgent);
  var args = ['-x', '-o', path_compile, '-e', 'do shell script "' + XREExeF + ' -P -no-remote &> /dev/null &"'];
  proc.runAsync(args, args.length, procFinOSA);
}
```

graphic of error thrown on double click of script.app:

[image: graphic of error thrown on double click of script.app]

Comment: solution here: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1126/shortcut-created-on-mac-with-osfile-but-cant-get-around-unidentified-developer-error/